# Ambiguous reference to forEach when listing mongoDB's database in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, lambda

I'm following this [guide](http://www.baeldung.com/java-mongodb) to try and setup a mongoDB database.

```
mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().forEach(System.out::println);
```

`getDatabaseNames()` is deprecated and replaced.

However this line gives the following error:

```
error: reference to forEach is ambiguous
    mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().forEach(System.out::println);
                                   ^
  both method forEach(Consumer<? super T>) in Iterable and method forEach(Block<? super TResult>) in MongoIterable match
  where T,TResult are type-variables:
    T extends Object declared in interface Iterable
    TResult extends Object declared in interface MongoIterable
```

The documentation states that listDatabaseNames() returns a `ListDatabasesIterable`, why can I not iterate through this list?

Comment: What's unclear in the error message? You can iterate on it. The problem is that there are two different ways (i.e. two different forEach() methods), and the compiler can't figure out the way you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can help the compiler resolve the ambiguity by casting to `Consumer<String>`

```
mongoClient.listDatabaseNames()
           .forEach((Consumer<String>) System.out::println);
```

Comment: For me, casting to (Consumer<? super String>) worked instead of (Consumer<String>). Can you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

`listDatabaseNames()` exposes to different `forEach` methods. One can receive as argument `Block<? super String> block` and the second one receive `Consumer<? super String> consumer`.
In order to avoid this ambiguity you will need to cast it to your needs.

```
  mongoClient1.listDatabaseNames()
              .forEach((Block<String>) System.out::println);
```

There is also an open issue about this [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2010)

Comment: downvoter, please justify your reasoning behind your decision of downvoting. If you consider my answer is not correct, help me out correct my answer if you know better

Comment: 1. you can use a forEach, and don't need to use a for loop to fix the issue. 2. the forEach() provided by MongoIterable is Java 8 lambda compliant, since it's a functional interface. If it were not, the compiler would precisely not generate this error message. The fact that it gives this error message shows that System.out::println can be inferred as a Block.

Comment: appreciate your reply. thanks. will update my answer

Comment: @JBNizet, let me know if this seems better or needs adjustments

Comment: It's OK now. Although I would just use Consumer<String>.

Comment: The linked issue is now 'closed' by deprecating the Block version. However, the compiler is still complaining, so that's a shoddy way to close an issue...

Answer (score 0):

This ambiguity can be resolved by casting to `(Consumer<? super String>)`

```
mongoClient.listDatabaseNames()
       .forEach((Consumer<? super String>)  name -> System.out.println(name));
```